# Data Archival - purging tool for MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Does anyone know a good data archiving and purging tool for MS Dynamics CRM 2011. I came across the [Ignify](http://www.ignify.com/DynamicsCRMArchive.asp) tool.
But I haven't been able to download any trials, so unable to check it out.
Any tool or strategy to archiving CRM data would be helpful.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm getting your aim right but there's a tool called ALM (Application Lifecycle Management, ADX Studios) by Shan McArthur (MVP on CRM) that can be used to data operation such as pulling out, storying in SVN and reimporting to an organization (the original or a new).

I'm not in any way affiliated with that company, nor do I know the author. I simply have heard about the software (in fact, today) and thought it could be of use. I'm not providing any linkage.